# Jinja SQL Equivalent in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, python, sql, node.js, jinja2

Is there any [SQL Jinja](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/jinjasql) like templating in NodeJs? There is a [SQL templating string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-template-strings) but it is not as powerful as SQL [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) in python.

Scenario:
I am using very long SQL queries for reporting purposes. The API is in NodeJS. I want to refactor the SQL queries using template engines. The intention is to use these template queries with any SQL(i.e. Postgres, MySQL, etc. in the future). I do not want to use ORM. Just want some templating engine similar to SQL Jinja which can dynamically generate SQL queries.